# Word for a Refined idea which is a combination of two previous ideas

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which means that my current solution is a refined version of my previous one, but it is also a combination of my previous idea and a 2nd idea. I found the following question, but it still isn't the word that I'm looking for.

[A word that means that when two elements are mixed they become stronger](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121392/a-word-that-means-that-when-two-elements-are-mixed-they-become-stronger/121414#121414)

Comment: Your idea is a synthesis of two previous ideas. That sounds much like your intended meaning.

Comment: Some REVISIONS can result in something stronger, too, but not necessarily. I think @Cerberus is spot-on with SYNTHESIS, however.

Comment: @cerberus..+1 for SYNTHESIS. Why not make it an answer..it fits in perfectly.

Comment: @MystiSinha: I was lazy...very well, then, it's done!

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is a **synthesis** of two previous ideas. That sounds much like your intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I also am partial to @Cerberus's choice of synthesis, but offer a few alternatives:

> integration, composite, unification, blend, amalgam