# Word for: Making stronger together

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, connotation

I'm looking for a word that implies a group of things (which are not good by themselves and somehow incomplete) become strong and somehow complete together.

Something like flocking or swarming but each of those do not have the "completing/improving/positive" connotation I'm looking for.  Any ideas?

Comment: *Unite*, perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A word that means that when two elements are mixed they become stronger](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121392/a-word-that-means-that-when-two-elements-are-mixed-they-become-stronger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d suggest ***[synergetic:](https://www.lexico.com/definition/synergetic)***

> Involving the interaction or cooperation of two or more organizations, substances, or other agents to produce a combined effect greater than the sum of their separate effects.
>
> - *‘we will develop a highly synergetic global management platform’
>     ‘the synergetic antioxidative effect of tocopherols in the presence of lycopene’*

Comment: I like ti but I find its a bit "buisnessy".  Is there anything most tangible (with a warmer connotation?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no term to connote generally the idea of combining and making  thereby a whole stronger than the uniting parts. The general verbs "coalesce", "amalgamate" and "unite" do not take into account anything else than the idea of combining. I would therefore use a phrase.

- **to coalesce/amalgamate/unite into a whole stronger than are in isolation the contributing parts they constitute**

SOED, 1995 ed., **coalesce** *v. i.* Grow or come together to form one whole; unite; combine; form a coalition.   LD MACAULAY    Who had bound himself..never to coalesce with Pitt.   C. DARWIN    The granules coalesce into larger masses.    M.GIROUARD    The elements that were to coalesce into 'Queen Anne'.

In a wide domain of application (organizations,  groups of people, robots, etc.), there exist an adjective with the  meaning of mutual reinforcement: **symbiotic**, SOED *transf. and fig.* mutually advantageous (from late 19th century). There is no corresponding verb.

[ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=9o5ZwuAFy08C&pg=PA78&dq=%22symbiotic%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA-r2k-NroAhWGHRQKHUu7BYwQ6AEIcDAH#v=onepage&q=%22symbiotic%22&f=false) The mechanical characteristics and functionalities of individual robots in a collective symbiotic system are of the utmost importance in order to confer suitable capabilities to the symbiotic robot organisms.

A shorter phrase could now be "**to coalesce symbiotically**".

It has the defect that an explicit superiority of the whole over the parts is not clearly meant although it seems an ineluctable consequence.